# use require on javascript client

Tags: javascript, require

I tried to use a require (like node.js) in javascript client without transpilers and without callbacks that need to wait a answer or anything that change my code to another code, somebody knows how to do a require like:

```
var a = require('library.js'); //sctricly this syntax not require.js
a.method('HI', 12);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: What reason do you have to avoid using something like webpack or browserify?

Comment: Because the output js code file generated by these tools is ugly and very difficult to maintaint without the original sources

Comment: That's why you set up a toolchain using task automation like `gulp` to automatically generate the output files whenever you make changes to the source, you're not expected to maintain the output code.

Comment: Why not? In many projects of many enterprises you need to maintain the output js code by many reasons

Comment: You might want to check [this tutorial](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto) out and look at the [example](https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto/tree/master/example) folder to get an idea of how to make a node.js application support the client-side environment using `require()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webpack for this. It supports both AMD and CommonJS modules.

```
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/
```

You cannot use this feature at present without using these libraries. Browser support is very limited. If you just want to see this in action, then I think Chrome Canary has a flag in chrome:flags which allows you to enable ES6 modules.

Answer (score -1):

require is a Node module, so you cannot use it on the client.

Comment: requirejs support some of the the features that support require of node.js but I want to do a require on a CSS or DOM too